# select down and up votes for each post php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, count

I have a forum where users can post questions and can upvote and downvote.

I want to get the `upvote` and `downvote` of each post.

What i did previously was do that in 3 sets queries.

```
$data = mysqli_query($con,"select * from posts");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
  $pid  = $row['post_id'];
  $up = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM up WHERE post_id = $pid"))['c'];
  $down = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM down WHERE post_id = $pid"))['c'];
}
```

Can anyone show me how can i do these things in **one single query** because if a get a lot of `posts` in 1st query then there will be lots of queries to do.

Comment: Well the first way you can optimize it is to put any column name instead of *. Especially the first query where you just want post_id.

Comment: Can you show the structure of your **posts** table?

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea Tis just for an example i know what u r talkin bout

Comment: @AmitThakur jobs done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subqueries and put everything in the first query.

This could be a good start :

```
$data = mysqli_query($con, "select posts.*, " . 
                           "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM up WHERE post_id = posts.post_id) as totalUp, " . 
                           "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM down WHERE post_id = posts.post_id) as totalDown " .
                           "from posts");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
  // ...
}
```

Comment: is it faster ? @forguesr

Comment: Yes : you will notice the difference if there is a lot of rows in the table `posts`. Like you pointed out, there will be a single query instead of many.  In fact a query inside a loop controlled by another query might be a smell that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: now is it really bad to use a query inside a loop controlled by query ? @forguesR (In extreme impossible conditions also ?)

Comment: Very often you can do the same thing with a single query instead of a loop and this is almost always faster because databases engine are heavily optimized to do this.

Comment: You might wanna take a look at this @forguesR   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806127/select-all-comments-with-all-posts-php-mysql

Answer (score 0):

you can use corelated subquery for this where upvotes 
and downvotes are counted based on the post id

```
SELECT p.*,
       ( select count(*)  from up where post_id = p.post_id ) as upVotesCount,
       ( select count(*)  from down where post_id = p.post_id ) as downVotesCount,
 FROM posts p
```

Comment: is it faster ? @radar

Comment: @RockFellerDumbstep, yes with proper indices, it would be faster. mysql engine would do the optimization needed.

Comment: You might wanna take a look at this @radar   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806127/select-all-comments-with-all-posts-php-mysql