# select all comments with all posts php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, subquery

I have a forum where users can post questions and can comment and tweet.

I want to get all the `comments` and `tweets` of each post.

What i did previously was do that in 3 sets queries.

```
$data = mysqli_query($con,"select * from posts");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
  $pid  = $row['post_id'];
  $dataCo = mysqli_query("SELECT comments.* FROM comments WHERE post_id = $pid");
  $dataTw = mysqli_query("SELECT tweets.* FROM tweets WHERE post_id = $pid");
  //2 while loop for comments and tweets

}
```

Can anyone show me how can i do these things in **one single query** because if a get a lot of `posts` in 1st query then there will be lots of queries to do.

OR

Maybe there is a faster way to do ?

Comment: Look into using a `join`...

Comment: if those tables have different structures, and different numbers of comments/tweets, then DON'T try to do it in a single query. you'll just suffer for the attempt.

Comment: they do have diff no of comments/tweets @MarcB . So will my queries be faster like that? or there is another way out

Comment: @MarcB -- I don't see how the table structure matters -- why not use an `outer join`?  Multiple nested queries in while loops are expensive.  Something like: `select p.post_id, c.whatever, t.whatever from posts p left join comments c on p.post_id = c.post_id left join tweets t on p.post_id = t.post_id order by p.post_id`  Perhaps it depends on how the OP wants to display the data, but this would return all the data in a single call...

Comment: ok but if i want only say post_id = 121 to show then i am getting lots of null posts along with 121! @sgeddes

Comment: @RockFellerDumbstep -- Add you're `where` criteria accordingly.  The `outer join` returns all posts, along with those matching by post_id on `comments` and `tweets`.  You'll need to update your php code to handle the looping/null checks/etc...

Comment: is it faster than pawel's answer?  @sgeddes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Mysql IN clause

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

In your example you have always 2*n + 1 queries to DB. Where n in number of returned rows in this query

```
$data = mysqli_query($con,"select * from posts");
```

If you use mysql IN Clause you will have only 3 queries.

Your queries should looks like

```
$dataCo = mysqli_query("SELECT comments.* FROM comments WHERE post_id IN (1,2,3,4)");
$dataTw = mysqli_query("SELECT tweets.* FROM tweets WHERE post_id IN (1,2,3,4)");
```

Numbers "1,2,3,4" are post_id returned in your first question.

Comment: how @pawelBrzoski? maybe ull explain a bit rather than giving a reference to `IN()` command

Comment: ok this is cool! now it is gonna be faster than using all those joins @pawelBrzoski ?

Comment: I would do it this way. This in simple in fast.